# Devise redirect after signing in user from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise

I'm trying to sign in and redirect a user to `home_path` if certain criteria are met, otherwise they are unapproved and redirected to another page. When I sign in the user through the controller, they are redirected to `users#show` though (users/:id).

How can I sign them in, and get it to redirect to `home_path` which is `'profile/home'` from the registrations controller?

registrations controller:

```
def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if resource.location === "New York, NY, United States"
      if (really long query)
        puts "accepted!"
        resource.approved = true 
        resource.save!
        sign_in(resource)
        home_path
      else
        puts "Not accepted"
        '/profile/waitlist'
      end
    else
      puts "City is not New York!"
      '/profile/waitlist'
    end
end
```

application controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   home_path
end
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are using the `sign_in_and_redirect_method` otherwise the url helpers won't get called.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FHelpers%3Asign_in_and_redirect